# Local broker (MQTT) based Publish/Subscribe using Android Application

Tags: android, node.js, mqtt

In my current project, I am using MQTT local broker based implementation and setup using [this link](http://wingsquare.com/blog/setting-up-mqtt-mosquitto-broker-in-ubuntu-linux/). The local broker based MQTT implementation is working perfectly.

At initially, I am using Node.js publisher and subscriber with this local broker to enable the exchange of messages and it works without internet connection also (as these devices are connected to the same network, mqtt API for local broker based implementation is like `http://192.168.0.105`).

Now, I would like to replace Node.js subscriber with Android application. My android application using mqtt paho library for communication and using mqtt API`mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883`. If I am using mqtt open broker i.e. mosquitto than Node.js publisher and Android application subscriber both are working properly (this case is talking about mosquitto based mqtt implementation using the API `mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883`).

Now, I want to use local broker based implementation in Android application. So I have to replace `mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883` API with `http://192.168.0.105` as I want to use local broker based mqtt implementation. When I use `http://192.168.0.105` API in the android code and deploy to mobile device, it displays error that **Unfortunately, Android Application has stopped** in andoid application.

**How to use local-broker based implementation in android application?**

Additionally sharing the code of Node.js publisher and subscriber.
Node.js publisher (local broker based implementation)

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('http://192.168.0.105');
setInterval(function() {
var data = {
     "tempValue" : Math.random(),
     "unitOfMeasurement" : 'C'
     };
client.publish('tempMeasurement', JSON.stringify(data));
}, 5000);
```

Node.js subscriber (local broker based implementation)

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('http://192.168.0.105');
client.subscribe('tempMeasurement'); 
client.on('message', function(topic, payload) {
       if (topic.toString() == "tempMeasurement") {  
       console.log("Mesage Received "+ payload.toString());
   }       
 });
```

Sharing code of MQTT Subscriber for better clarity:

```
package iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.MemoryPersistence;

public class MQTTSubscriber {

// URI for open MQTT broker
// public static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883";
public static final String BROKER_URL = "mqtt://192.168.0.105";

private MqttClient client;

public MQTTSubscriber(PubSubMiddleware pubsub) {
    try {
        client = new MqttClient(BROKER_URL, MqttClient.generateClientId(),
                new MemoryPersistence());

        client.setCallback(new PushCallback(pubsub));
        client.connect();

    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void subscribe(String topicName) throws MqttException {

    client.subscribe(topicName);

    System.out.println("Subscribed. Topic: " + topicName);
}

}
```

and subscribing for `tempMeasurement` using following code:

```
package framework;

 import iotsuite.common.Logger;
 import iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.PubSubMiddleware;
 import iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.Subscriber;
 import iotsuite.semanticmodel.Device;
 import android.util.Log;
 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
 import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

 public abstract class SmartHomeApp implements Runnable, Subscriber {

protected final PubSubMiddleware myPubSubMiddleware;
protected final Device myDeviceInfo;
Gson gson = new Gson();

public SmartHomeApp(PubSubMiddleware pubSubM, Device deviceInfo) {

    this.myPubSubMiddleware = pubSubM;
    this.myDeviceInfo = deviceInfo;
    postInitialize();

}

protected void postInitialize() {
    subscribeDisplayTemp();

}

@Override
public void notifyReceived(String eventName, Object arg) {
    try {

        if (eventName.equals("tempMeasurement")) {
            Logger.log(myDeviceInfo.getName(), "TempMonitoringApp",
                    "Notification Received tempMeasurement ");
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(arg.toString())
                    .getAsJsonObject();
            double tempValue = jsonObject.get("tempValue").getAsDouble();
            // double yahootempValue =
            // jsonObject.get("yahootempValue").getAsDouble();
            TempStruct tempStruct = new TempStruct(tempValue, "C");
            System.out.println("tempValue is " + tempValue
                    + " in framework");
            Log.i("tempValue", "tempValue is received in framework");
            onNewDisplayTempNotify(tempStruct);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
}

public abstract void onNewDisplayTempNotify(TempStruct arg);

public void subscribeDisplayTemp() {

    this.myPubSubMiddleware.subscribe(this, "tempMeasurement");
}

}
```

Using the above code, I would like to display the `tempValue` received from Node.js code to Android application. Error from Android is as follow:

```
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793): Process: com.example.android,      PID: 21793
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity}:       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at  org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.validateURI(MqttClient.java:204)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:175)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.MQTTPublisher.<init>(MQTTPublisher.java:21)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.PubSubMiddleware.<init>(PubSubMiddleware.java:58)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at      iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.IoTSuiteFactory.getInstance(IoTSuiteFactory.java:16)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at  sim.deviceD9.Startup.setUpNode(Startup.java:25)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at sim.deviceD9.Startup.startDevice(Startup.java:63)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at com.example.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
01-04 23:03:26.786: E/AndroidRuntime(21793):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Try with `mqtt://192.168.0.103` instead of `http`

Comment: Try changing `BROKER_URL` to `tcp://192.168.0.105:1883`

Comment: @hardillb- Thanks for the swift response. It's working. Could you please write this as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your URI is using the `http://` scheme. `http://` is for connecting to HTTP servers not MQTT brokers.

You need to use the `tcp://` URI for Android (this might work for NodeJS as well, but `mqtt://` definately works for NodeJS

`mqtt://192.168.0.105`

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.0.105');
setInterval(function() {
var data = {
     "tempValue" : Math.random(),
     "unitOfMeasurement" : 'C'
     };
client.publish('tempMeasurement', JSON.stringify(data));
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Again the same problem with Android application. It deploying to android mobile, I could not able to open the app and it displays the error Unfortunately, Android Application has stopped. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Without seeing the whole stacktrace it's impossible to say. Edit the question to include the error message (All of it)

Comment: @hardillb- I will update question soon with whole stacktrace.

Comment: Include the connection code from the Android app as well

Comment: @hardillb- Could you please check as I have updated post with android code and error also.