# Local broker (MQTT) based Publish mechanism from Android Application

Tags: android, node.js, mqtt

With the reference to question [Local broker (MQTT) based Publish/Subscribe using Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431163/local-broker-mqtt-based-publish-subscribe-using-android-application). In my current project, I would like to **send data from Android application to Node.js using local broker based MQTT implementation**.

As per the solution provided in the above mentioned question, I am using the same solution to send data from Android application (`tcp://192.168.0.105`Android API for local broker) to Node.js app `mqtt://192.168.0.105` (Node.js side API for with the ip of local broker), but I could not able to send data from Android to Node.js app. Here `192.168.0.105` is the IP address of the local broker. If I use `mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883` API on Node.js side and `tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883` API on client side than it works perfectly.

**Using the local broker-based API, the entire project doesn't display any error.** Sharing the log of the android project for the better clarity. It also prints the tempValue using the following log (line 1 in the log).

```
01-12 22:00:07.348: I/System.out(23135): tempValue is41.0in Android Smart Home App
01-12 22:00:07.349: W/System.err(23135): Client is not connected (32104)
01-12 22:00:07.349: W/System.err(23135):    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:27)
01-12 22:00:07.349: W/System.err(23135):    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.internalSend(ClientComms.java:101)
01-12 22:00:07.349: W/System.err(23135):    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:119)
01-12 22:00:07.349: W/System.err(23135):    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic.publish(MqttTopic.java:62)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.MQTTPublisher.publish(MQTTPublisher.java:34)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at iotsuite.pubsubmiddleware.PubSubMiddleware.publish(PubSubMiddleware.java:89)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at framework.SmartHomeApp.SetTempFromGUI(SmartHomeApp.java:40)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at logic.LogicSmartHomeApp$1.onNewSetTempCommand(LogicSmartHomeApp.java:56)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at deviceImpl.AndroidSmartHomeApp.onClick(AndroidSmartHomeApp.java:77)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
01-12 22:00:07.350: W/System.err(23135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-12 22:00:07.350: I/System.out(23135): Publishing data in Smart Home App
01-12 22:00:23.332: W/System(24876): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/Settings/lib/arm
01-12 22:01:45.401: W/System(24934): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.goibibo-1/lib/arm
01-12 22:01:45.634: W/System(24934): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/n/armeabi-v7a
01-12 22:01:45.635: W/System(24934): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/n/armeabi
```

The `tcp://192.168.0.105`,`mqtt://192.168.0.105`, and `http://192.168.0.105` APIs work with Node.js local broker based implementation.**The Node.js code of the application as shown below:**

```
    var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect('http://192.168.0.105');
client.subscribe('tempMeasurement'); 
console.log("waiting for tempValue");
client.on('message', function(topic, payload) {     
        if (topic.toString() == "tempMeasurement") {  
            console.log("Mesage Received "+ payload.toString());
        }           
});
```

The code of Android application is the same that I have posted in the above mentioned question. Am I missing in the solution provided by Hardillb in this implementation?

Comment: `mqtt.connect('http://192.168.0.105')` Are you really having this line in your node app?

Comment: @PavelZdenek- yes this works for local broker based implementation.

Comment: Do you really have `http` there ???

Comment: @PavelZdenek- For local broker based implementation, you can use `http://192.168.0.105`, `mqtt://192.168.0.105` and `tcp://192.168.0.105` as well for the API on Node.js side.

Comment: In your previous question, you have accepted an answer which is telling you that `http` cannot be used for connecting to MQTT. I suggest you believe it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133048/discussion-between-saurabh13-and-pavel-zdenek).